# Probablilities of hatching eggs

Tags: probability

I breed snakes.  I have a "clutch" or litter of 8 eggs.  Because there is a recessive gene involved and the parents are both heterozygous, each egg has a 1:4 chance of being an albino snake, making a 3:4 chance of it being a "normal" appearing snake.  What are the odds that 7/8 of these eggs will produce albino snakes?  Can someone explain to me the math in solving this?

Comment: Yes you need Binomial distribution

Comment: If (as implicit in your statement) you have independence between the eggs, yes, you are dealing with a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), with parameters $n=8$ and $p=\frac{1}{4}$. Also, be careful with snakes.

Answer (score 5):

Each egg has $\frac 14$ chance of being an albino snake, and $\frac 34$ chance of being a normal snake. So the probability that among these $8$ eggs, $7$ of them are albino and one of them is normal will be a binomial distribution, where $n=8,x=7,p=\frac 14, q=\frac 34$:
$$
P(7)=\binom{8}{7} \left(\frac 14\right)^7\left(\frac 34\right)^1 = 8\cdot \frac{3}{4^8} = \frac{3}{8192}
$$

Comment: Not really, you are forgetting all possible combinations here (there is an $\binom{8}{7}$ factor.)

Comment: @ClementC. My mistake, edited. Thanks

Comment: **PS:** That *is* the probability for *exactly* 7 of the 8 hatching albino.  The probability for *at least* 7 of the 8 *adds* the probability of all 8 being so.  $P(8) = (\tfrac 1 4)^8$.  (*If* that is what the OP meant instead.) $$P(7)+P(8) = \dfrac{24+1}{4^8}= \frac{25}{65536}$$